# Forward email using Amazon SES: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, smtp, postfix-mta, amazon-ses

I have an EC2 instance with postfix installed. There are no inboxes. All email is forwarded using settings users define in postfixadmin. When I enable Amazon SES, my website can send emails just fine. The problem arrises when I forward mail. In the email header, the "from" field remains the same. Amazon SES rejects this since it is not from a verified sender or domain.

How can I remedy this? I want to continue using Amazon SES to make sure I don't get blacklisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot of options here. Amazon SES is a mail notification service more than a pure SMTP server. Because of this, all of your from emails/domains must be previously verified and all of your mail sessions must be properly authenticated.

The only alternative i can figure out is to configure postfix as a proxy instead of a relay, so it replaces the from header with a well known address, verified by SES, and properly authenticates in SES.